# element placement order in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a CRUD, and when I click on the button to make a new post, a div is rendered with the post content. The problem is that I want to change the order of posts, actually when a new post is created it is placed below the oldest post, and I want newer posts to be rendered on top.

```
    function MainScreen() {
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts)
    
      const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
      const [content, setContent] = useState("");
      const [buttonGreyOut, setButtonGreyOut] = useState("#cccccc");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (title && content !== "") {
          setButtonGreyOut("black");
        } else {
          setButtonGreyOut("#cccccc");
        }
      },[title, content]);
    
    
    
      const handleSubmitSendPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(postsSlice.actions.addPost({title, content}))
        setTitle('')
        setContent('')
      };
    
      const handleChangeTitle = (text) => {
        setTitle(text);
      };
    
      const handleChangeContent = (text) => {
        setContent(text);
      };
    
    
      const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();
    
      if (user === '') {
        return <Navigate to="/" />
      } else {
        return (
          <div className="containerMainScreen">
            {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} />}
            <div className="bar">
              <h1>Codeleap</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="boxPost">
              <h2 style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>What's on your mind?</h2>
              <h2>Title</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmitSendPost}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Hello World"
                  name="name"
                  value={title}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeTitle(e.target.value)}
                ></input>
                <h2>Content</h2>
                <textarea
                  placeholder="Content"
                  name="content"
                  value={content}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeContent(e.target.value)}
                ></textarea>
                <button
                  className="createButton"
                  type="submit"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: buttonGreyOut }}
                  disabled={!title || !content}
                >
                  CREATE
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
      
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <div className="boxPost">
                <div className="bar">
                  <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                  <MdDeleteForever
                    className="icon"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setOpenModal(true);
                    }}
                  />
                  <FiEdit
                    style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "45px", paddingLeft: "23px" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div id="postowner">
                    <h3>@{user}</h3>
                  <h3>25 minutes ago</h3>
                  <br></br>
                  <textarea style={{ border: "none" }}>{post.content}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
      
      
      }export default MainScreen;
```

my postslice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    // add one post to the array.
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload); // modifies the draft state.
    },
    // replace the entire array.
    replacePosts: (state, action) => action.payload
  }
});

export default postsSlice
```

screenshot of the page:

https://ibb.co/52MS2P1

Comment: Well it sounds like in `addPost` you should be *prepending*, not *appending* the posts. Can't be specific as to what to change, since the code for that function isn't in the question.

Comment: In the addpost, instead of appending the posts, do the prepending .
If you are keeping posts in an array check this function for prepending items in the array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: I looked about prepending, but I couldn't figure out how I would implement it in my posts array... could you give an example of use in redux?

Answer (score 0):

Well the what your code solves is array `posts` has all the elements as they are and new post are added to the last of the array and old post are in the starting. So  they are actually implicitly sorted by the time they are added into this array

you can try to reverse your posts array every time you render it.

for reversing you can use `.reverse()`

so like this `posts.reverse().map....`

Comment: I tried to do this, but when I go to create the second post, it returns this error:  TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your redux reducer/action and place new object in the first position.

something like this:

```
return {...pervState, posts: [newPost, ...pervState.posts]}
```

Comment: I added my action/reducer to the post to help

Comment: replace state.push(action.payload) with state = [action.payload, ...state]

Comment: when I replace the code as you said, the new post is not created